# I am a beginner at javascript .My code is not running .My codes are given below.where have I done mistake?

Tags: javascript

My code is not running. My codes are given below.W here have I done mistake?

```
function age(userage) {
  if (userage >= 18) {
    document.querySelector(".if_else_2").innerHTML = "<h1 style='color:green'>You are mature</h1>";
  } else {
    document.querySelector(".if_else_2").innerHTML = "<h1 style='color:yellow'>You are children</h1>";
  }

  age(20);
}
```

Comment: You are calling your `age` function from within that function itself. Move the `age(20)`  to after the closing bracket of the function.

Comment: Can you include relevant sections of HTML code?

Comment: I guess the above code is going to infinite recursion. Can you check the logic once?

Answer (score 0):

Call `age` after you define it, not within the function body.

```
function age(userage) {
  if (userage >= 18) {
    document.querySelector(".if_else_2").innerHTML = "<h1 style='color:green'>You are mature</h1>";
  } else {
    document.querySelector(".if_else_2").innerHTML = "<h1 style='color:yellow'>You are children</h1>";
  }
}

age(20);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to call the age function outside the declaration.

```
function age(userage) {
    if (userage >= 18) {
        document.querySelector(".if_else_2").innerHTML = "<h1 style='color:green'>You are mature</h1>";
    } else {
        document.querySelector(".if_else_2").innerHTML = "<h1 style='color:yellow'>You are children</h1>";
    }
}
age(20);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the function in the outside scope. Also if you call the function outside it will be recursive for infinite, so put the age(20) outside function scope.

```
function age(userage) {
      if (userage >= 18) {
        document.querySelector(".if_else_2").innerHTML = "<h1 style='color:green'>You are mature</h1>";
      } else {
        document.querySelector(".if_else_2").innerHTML = "<h1 style='color:yellow'>You are children</h1>";
      }
}

age(20);
```